# Are there finite dimensional representations of the Poincaré algebra with non-nilpotent momentum generators?

Tags: representation-theory, poincare-symmetry

The matrix representations of the Poincaré algebra that I am familiar with, have a nilpotent set of momentum generators: $p^\mu p^\nu = 0$. I am wondering whether it is possible to have finite dimensional representations of the Poincaré algebra, where the momenta generators are not nilpotent, and if so, what these representations look like.

I am obviously not looking for a classification of representations of this non-simple algebra, I am just wondering whether an example of the above type exists, or of course whether there is some simple proof showing that it cannot.

---

For some background, a representation I typically consider can be induced by a set of gamma matrices with signature $(2,4)$. Labeling the two timelike indices as $0$ and $5$, and the spacelike ones as $1,2,3$ and $4$, we can take

$p^\mu \sim \gamma^\mu \gamma^4 - \gamma^\mu \gamma^5$

and

$m^{\mu\nu} \sim \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu$

which is a nice representation of the Poincaré algebra. In this representation we clearly have $p^\mu p^\nu = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is too long and complicated for a comment… but I don’t think so.  The momenta operators will act as tensor operators connecting the various $so(3,1)$ multiplets of your representation, so if they are not nilpotent you would just add up multiplets by repeatedly acting with the momenta.

I have in mind something similar to [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/J-Repka-2/publication/234997228_Some_finite_dimensional_indecomposable_representations_of_E2/links/56f95d4908ae81582bf4384d/Some-finite-dimensional-indecomposable-representations-of-E2.pdf) where it’s done for $\mathfrak{e}(2)$.  Of course the structure is not Poincaré but the in there they show that $p^2$ must be nilpotent because there are finitely many $so(2)$ weights in the irrep.  You might be able to adapt their proof if you can organize your commuting momenta so some raise or lower the so(3,1) weights, as was done there for $p_\pm$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link! I'll have a look at generalizing the e(2) case, but either way it gives a clear intuitive picture why it likely can't be done.

Comment: Actually I think the e(2) case generalizes directly. Consider any mμν, these all have at least one complex eigenvalue. Then consider $p^\pm = p^\mu \pm (i) p^\nu$ (i as needed). These will act as raising/lowering operators, hence finite dimensionality of the full rep implies $(p^\pm)^k = 0$ for some k. Since the $p^\mu$ all commute, we conclude $(p^\mu)^{2k}=0$ (as an upper bound). Do you agree?

Comment: @Stijn yes that would be the idea.  Can you send some references… interesting problem actually.

Comment: This was just based on the paper you linked, combined with the realization that we just need a way to go nicely from (necessarily) nilpotent positive/negative roots in a finite dimensional matrix algebra ($p^\pm$), to the actual matrix generators of the real form ($p^\nu$), whose nilpotency we wanted to establish. Due to the commutativity of the $p^\mu$, this is very simple in the Poincaré algebra. (The same trick does not work, and hence does not give nilpotent generators, in e.g. the finite dimensional irreps of su(2) -- $\sigma^1 \pm i \sigma^2$ are nilpotent, but not the $\sigma^i$.)

Comment: Just to add for concreteness: $(p^\mu)^{2k} \sim (p^+ \pm p^-)^{2k}$ which expanded out gives a polynomial in $p^+ $ and $p^-$ (they commute), of total degree $2k$, meaning each term contains $(p^+)^k$ or $(p^-)^k$ somewhere. I.e. each term in the expansion of $(p^\mu)^{2k}$, and hence the total, is zero.

Comment: @Stijn I was thinking more of background to your original question, i.e. references to "a representation I typically consider can be induced by a set of gamma matrices with signature (2,4)."

Comment: Ah, ok! I encountered this as a statement/tool in research papers, so I don't really have the nicest source for this.. Still, you can find a self-contained list of ingredients in section 2.1 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.03083, although the general structure is not stated too clearly. Alternatively, equations (3.3)-(3.8) in https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.03554 give gamma matrices and show how to pick a physical basis for the conformal algebra by singling out one timelike and one spacelike index of so(4,2), but it's a bit in the middle of a different discussion..

Comment: Here we're viewing the Poincaré algebra as a subalgebra of the conformal algebra so(4,2) $\simeq$ su(2,2).